# Error regarding missing 1 required positional argument while using one hot encoder with feature engineer

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding, feature-engineering

This code ran smoothly:
from feature_engine.categorical_encoders import OneHotCategoricalEncoder

```
ohe_enc= OneHotCategoricalEncoder(top_categories=None, variables=['x1','x2','x3','x4'], drop_last=True)

ohe_enc.fit(X_train)
```

This gave me errors:

```
tmp=ohe_enc.transform(X_train)
tmp.head()
```

> TypeError: check_is_fitted() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'attributes'

Any idea what I am missing here?

X_train sample
X1           x2.          x3.             x4
substitute   Alone.       Qualified.      New
Permanent.   Accompnied.  Non Qualified.  Experienced

Comment: Please share a sample of X_train

Comment: X_train are 4 categorical columns (only categorical chosen for one hot encoding)